# How to INSERT INTO one table and one of the columns automatically 'INSERT INTO' another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship

I have created two tables one named 'A' and one named 'B'. They both share a column called ID.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
ID int NOT NULL,
random1 char(10),
random2 char(10)
);

CREATE TABLE B (
ID int NOT NULL,
random3 char(10),
random4 char(10)
);
```

I'm trying to make it so when I INSERT INTO Table A, it copies/inserts itself into Table B:

```
INSERT INTO A (ID, random1, random2)
VALUES (123, 'Value2', 'Value3');
```

`SELECT * FROM TABLE A` should return

```
| ID | random1 | random2 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 123  | Value2   | Value3 |
```

and
`SELECT * FROM TABLE B` should return

```
| ID | random3 | random4 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 123  | NULL   | NULL |
```

I tried to use relationships/Primary-Foreign connections to achieve it but to no avail.

This is probably not the best way of making the table but I have already finished most of the other work and this is one of the last things to do.

Comment: The way you have it written, just add a second insert statement with the same Value1? But I think you might have oversimplied your issue.

Comment: Maybe `INSERT INTO A (ID, random1, random2) OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO B (ID) VALUES (123, 'Value2', 'Value3');`

Comment: The is no magic switch to make the happen. You could write a trigger to do it, but I would recommend not doing that as it hides the logic and makes it hard to maintain. Really just use 2 insert statements and provide the id to both of them. I also wonder why you have a relationship like that between 2 tables without it being a proper foreign key?

Comment: @Charlieface That worked like a charm, thank you very much sir. I didn't understand the documentation on "inserted" that much and was trying to do

`INSERT INTO A (ID, random1, random2) OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO B (ID) VALUES (123);`

Comment: Note that that only works if `B` is not part of a FK relationship and has no check constraints. Otherwise you need separate `INSERT` statements, or a trigger.